# PHP logon script syntax error

Tags: php, syntax, authentication

I'm trying to use a PHP login form tutorial I found somewhere online, and all works well until I reach a certain part where I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\Okinawa\login3.php on line 3
```

Since I am new to PHP coding, I have no idea what is wrong with the script which is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']){
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

Like I said, I just copy/pasted. If anyone could point out what the problem is I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one ")"

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `)` on the IF statement.

Basically, when you get an error like this ("Unexpected X"), it is trying to tell you that it expected something, but found "x" instead. At that point you should look for that character and see what should be before it that is breaking the parser from working correctly.

Also - that problem is in the tutorial as well; I would point it out for the author, as this isn't that obvious for someone new with PHP to spot. (And for the sake of tutorials integrity :))